# Javascript ERROR, undefined, not an object

Tags: javascript, controller, mapping

I am new in JavaScript, And I am trying to map my controller's buttons and leds for mixxx application. Is that an object, an array? var is missing.

```
BehringerCMDMM1.leds = [
    // Master
    { "shiftButton" : 0x12 },
    // Deck 1
    {  "sync" : 0x30  },
    // Deck 2
    {  "sync" : 0x33  }
];
```

I have an error here,

```
BehringerCMDMM1.shiftButton = function (channel, control, value, status, group) {
// Note that there is no 'if (value)' here so this executes both when the shift button is pressed and when it is released.
// Therefore, BehringerCMDMM1.shift will only be true while the shift button is held down
var deck = BehringerCMDMM1.groupToDeck(group);
BehringerCMDMM1.shift = !BehringerCMDMM1.shift // '!' inverts the value of a boolean (true/false) variable
BehringerCMDMM1.setLED(BehringerCMDMM1.leds[deck]["shiftButton"], BehringerCMDMM1.shift);
```

}

about "shiftButton" as undefined.

also I have this function

```
BehringerCMDMM1.setLED = function(value, status) {

status = status ? 0x7F : 0x00;
midi.sendShortMsg(0x94, value, status);
```

}

This is from a javascript file I found on the internet created for a different controller. So, I am trying things to understand how can I configure mine.

Comment: Undefined is not an object usually means some function is returning undefined

Comment: or he's trying to execute a function that isn't actually there, like `obj.aslkdjf()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BehringerCMDMM1.leds` is an array of objects. Within that array, the element at index 0 is an object that has a `shiftButton` property. Thus, the only way to get the `0x12` value in your example is to do this:

`BehringerCMDMM1.leds[0]['shiftButton']`

So when this code executes...

`var deck = BehringerCMDMM1.groupToDeck(group);`

...the value of `deck` is probably something other than 0, and you're accessing one of the `sync` objects in the `BehringerCMDMM1.leds` array. For example, if the value of `deck` was 1, then this...

`BehringerCMDMM1.leds[deck]['shiftButton']`

...will be `undefined` because you're effectively doing this:

`BehringerCMDMM1.leds[1]['shiftButton']`

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

> I am new in JavaScript, And I am trying to map my controller's buttons and leds for mixxx application. Is that an object, an array?

You have a array of objects.

> var is missing.

You should test what is inside yout deck variable. Try this:

```
console.log(deck);
if (deck in BehringerCMDMM1.leds) {
    BehringerCMDMM1.setLED(BehringerCMDMM1.leds[deck]["shiftButton"], BehringerCMDMM1.shift);
} else {
    console.log("Index: "+deck+" doesn't exist");
}
```

Comment: If your var deck has a string, maybe you should refactor your code to something like this: BehringerCMDMM1.leds = {
    "Master": { "shiftButton" : 0x12 },
    "Deck1": {  "sync" : 0x30  },
    "Deck2": {  "sync" : 0x33  }
};